# How to start Spring Boot app without depending on Pivotal GemFire cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, geode, spring-data-gemfire

I have a Spring Boot app with a Pivotal GemFire `ClientCache` instance configured and its corresponding domain objects. I am also using Spring Boot Test for unit testing. For every test case execution, either through class or Maven build, Spring `ApplicationContext` fails to load if the GemFire cache is down.

How to start Spring Boot application without depending on GemFire cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I follow exactly what you mean by...

> "*For every test case execution, either through class or Maven build, Spring `ApplicationContext` fails to load if the GemFire cache is down.*"

Are you recreating the `ClientCache` instance for each test case (method) in your test class?

If so, then this can be tricky to do since even after calling `ClientCache.close()`, GemFire may not have completely "closed" and released all the resources used by the `ClientCache` instance.  However, usually that does not prevent the Spring `ApplicationContext` from being recreated on subsequent test case executions.  It usually just leads to subsequent test failures since the `ClientCache` instance is dirty, or stale, retaining old state from the previous (or last) test case execution.

Are you also using Spring's `@DirtiesContext` on your test case method as well?

Usually, it is wise to cycle the `ApplicationContext` and GemFire cache instance (e.g. `ClientCache`) per test class, where each test case method in the test class will use the same `ApplicationContext` and `ClientCache` instance; this is the most ideal.

With that, I have 2 things to share with you:

1. First, have a look at the new [***Spring Boot for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire***](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode) project.  Documentation is [here](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot-data-geode-build/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/).  I [announced](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/26/spring-boot-for-apache-geode-pivotal-gemfire-1-0-0-m1-released) the availability of this project nearly a month ago now.  This project takes a "client-side" perspective to building Spring Boot applications with Pivotal GemFire.  That is, it gives you an auto-configured `ClientCache` instance by default.
2. Specifically, have a look at *Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire's* test suite, beginning [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/tree/master/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure).  Nearly all these test classes use a `ClientCache` instance and test various aspects of Pivotal GemFire, such as CQ's or Security, etc.
3. In certain test classes, I used a "mock" `ClientCache` instance (for example, this [test class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/config/annotation/DurableClientConfigurationIntegrationTests.java), and this [test configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/config/annotation/DurableClientConfigurationIntegrationTests.java#L122) in particular).  However, in many other cases, I used a live GemFire `ClientCache` instance, for [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/cache/client/SpringBootApacheGeodeClientCacheApplicationIntegrationTests.java) or this [test class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/security/ssl/AutoConfiguredSslIntegrationTests.java), which is interesting since this test class even [launches a server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/security/ssl/AutoConfiguredSslIntegrationTests.java#L74-L77) for the `ClientCache` instance (the test itself) to connect to.
4. All the test coordination logic in *Spring Boot for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire* is provided by another new project, [***Spring Test for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire***](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-data-geode).  Unfortunately, *Spring Test for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire* is still largely a WIP, so does not have documentation yet.  However, I have used this new test project extensively to test *Spring Boot for Apache Geode/Pivotal GemFire*.  You will see its presence in the extension classes, like [`ForkingClientServerIntegrationTestsSupport`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/master/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/security/ssl/AutoConfiguredSslIntegrationTests.java#L69), and so on.

In summary, use the new ***Spring Boot for Pivotal GemFire*** & ***Spring Test for Pivotal GemFire*** project as your guide for writing more effective Unit and Integration tests.

Finally, if you have an example GitHub repository reproducing your problem, I can help point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
John

Comment: John. Thanks for your reply and apologies for not explaining clearly. I have a gemfire cluster and my application is a client cache. For my unit testing i dont want to interact with cluster, i am fine with local cache. Can i achieve that if i keep a local client cache config under src/test/resources in order to override the actual gemfire config in src/main/java?

Comment: Hi Sudharasn- Yes, absolutely achievable.  Have a look at this test class from SBDG's test suite: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.0.0.M1/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/repository/AutoConfiguredRepositoriesIntegrationTests.java  Keep in mind, SBDG creates a `ClientCache` instance by default.  This test uses the `ClientCache` and ...

Comment: the "Customers" Region (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.0.0.M1/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/repository/AutoConfiguredRepositoriesIntegrationTests.java#L66-L67) to perform Region ops (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.0.0.M1/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/repository/AutoConfiguredRepositoriesIntegrationTests.java#L94-L98).

Comment: There is no server/cluster involved in this test.  You simply just need to make your client Region data policy a "LOCAL" one (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.0.0.M1/spring-geode-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/geode/boot/autoconfigure/repository/AutoConfiguredRepositoriesIntegrationTests.java#L105) and then a cluster of servers is unnecessary. Only when your client Region is a PROXY or CACHING_PROXY is a server required.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For your unit tests, use a different profile. Say **application-ut.yaml** and ask spring not to use any cache implementation library:

**application-ut.yaml** (add below entry and remove whatever implementation u configured for Gemfire)

```
spring.cache.type : simple
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring's Cache Abstraction and using Pivotal GemFire as the caching provider.